# `node.contains` is undefined in IE 11 when calling from a React ref in IE 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know why `element.contains` would be undefined in IE11? [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains), this function is supported in IE, but when I attempt to use it from a React [DOM ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) I get an error. Here's a rough example of the React code that I'm using to make the call:

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // stuff
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
      if (this.list.contains(e.target)) {
        // stuff
      }
    }.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul ref={c => { this.list = c }}>
        // stuff
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

In IE 11, this code generates the following error:

[image: Object doesn't support property or method error]

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

**UPDATE:**

Oddly, I've discovered that `this.dropdown` references the React component, whereas `this.dropdown.dropdown` points to the HTML element. So that `this.dropdown.dropdown.contains` refers to the correct method! So this, I suppose, is the thing to explain...

Comment: What is the type of `this.list`? `contains` is supported for strings and arrays.

Comment: The link you shared is just a generic search for "contains" across CanIUse-- nothing specifically related to Element.contains...

Comment: Also, there's a bad character (\\) in your code at the end of line two-- if this is copy paste from your actual code, I would expect it to complain...

Comment: I updated the support link to MDN instead, table near the bottom. Also it's technically `node.contains()` rather than `element.contains()` I think.

Comment: Alexander Nied thanks for identifying the typo in my pseudocode, but as I noted the code is an example of the kind of thing I'm doing that generates the error. The error pictured is quite specific, as you can see.

Comment: Yeah, there is a broken link in the MDN page noting that "Internet Explorer only supports contains() for elements."  But it seems like the issue you are looking at is Element-specific, so that shouldn't be the source of the issue...

Comment: @fraxture - OK, gotcha, sorry, I missed that it was a rough example, not actual code.